# Reset AUTO INCREMENT by the order of another column

Tags: mysql

I'm looking find a way to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT on my events table by the ORDER of start ASC

I've looked everywhere but currently not found an answer

The issue is events get deleted all the time and it causes massive gaps in the Auto  Incement for example we skip form ID 200  to 768 because that list of events was deleted

Comment: Typically manually intervening with an auto increment column is not best practice.  Perhaps you can include more information about why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Does it matter if 200 is followed by 768? **It should not**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = [Your Incremental Value Here];
query start auto-increment from given incremental value.